# Using static folders with nested routes in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, static, nested-routes

I have trouble getting files from the correct folders when using a nested route in Node JS.

In a standard route like:

```
router.get('/something', (req, res) => {
  res.render('something.html')
})
```

This `<img src="img/image-123.jpg">` inside `something.html` works.

However, it doesn't work in `createProduct.html` using this route:

```
router.get('/admin/createProduct', (req, res) => {
  res.render('createProduct.html')
})
```

because the browser tries to look for `admin/img/image-123.jpg` which doesn't exist.

I have both routes in an `index.js` file using `app.use(require('./routes/index'))`

And these are the static folders:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'scripts')));
```

This is my file structure:

[image]

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Don't use path relative URLs for your images in your HTML.  Instead, start the image URLs in the HTML with `/` so they are not relative to the path of the page and can easily be handled by a simple `express.static()` in your server.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to access static files in subroutes in /admin:

```js
app.use('/admin', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```